# How to interpret "ダメな時はダメ"?

Tags: expressions, slang

So, I would like to better understand the expression:

> ダメな時はダメ

I usually see it used practically alone, in a no-good situation.

Is it something like: "Impossible is impossible"? More to the line of "That was no good"? Something different?

[This tweet-pic](https://twitter.com/aferide100/status/478027008501227520/photo/1) may serve as an example.

Comment: Do you understand 「やばい… ゆで卵の茹でが甘かったのでチンしたらスーパーオウンゴールしてもーた… 」 from that image?  If you don't, my answer would only sound "off" if I posted it.

Comment: @非回答者 Yup, (I think) I do understand :)

Comment: Great.  I asked because not too many J-learners would know what チンする or してもーた meant.  I will post my answer, then.

Comment: And to anyone who is curious: チンする is slang for microwaving, and 〜してもーた is basically the same as 〜してしまった.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My best translation would be "When it rains, it pours."

In the image you provided, the speaker has just had two bad things happen to him in a row.

1) Failed at boiling the eggs the way he liked them.

2) Tried to make up for it by heating the eggs in the microwave and they exploded.